# What's wrong with the SQLite Query

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

```
SELECT
    MessageMaster.MessageId,
    MessageMaster.MessageType,
    MessageMaster.MessageDescription,
    MD1.DetailType,
    MD1.DetailValue,
    MD2.DetailType,
    MD2.DetailValue
FROM
(
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM MessageMaster 
        INNER JOIN MessageMasterDetail
            ON MessageMaster.MessageId = MessageMasterDetail.MessageId
    ) AS TAB1
    INNER JOIN MessageDetail AS MD1
        ON TAB1.DetailId = MD1.DetailId
)
LEFT JOIN MessageDetail AS MD2
    ON TAB1.AssociatedDetailId = MD2.DetailId;
```

It shows me the error. I don't know what's wrong with that. I've 3 tables attached here [image: Image here.]

Answer (score 1):

You can't access `TAB1` in the last join because it's outside the `FROM`.So give an alias to the result set say `TAB2` and use it in the last join and you have to change the `MD1` and `MessageMaster` to `TAB2` since both are not available at the level.

```
SELECT
    TAB2.MessageId,
    TAB2.MessageType,
    TAB2.MessageDescription,
    TAB2.DetailType,
    TAB2.DetailValue,
    MD2.DetailType,
    MD2.DetailValue
FROM
(
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM MessageMaster 
        INNER JOIN MessageMasterDetail
            ON MessageMaster.MessageId = MessageMasterDetail.MessageId
    ) AS TAB1
    INNER JOIN MessageDetail AS MD1
        ON TAB1.DetailId = MD1.DetailId
) TAB2
LEFT JOIN MessageDetail AS MD2
    ON TAB2.AssociatedDetailId = MD2.DetailId;
```

Comment: I don't think this will run either.  The `MessageMaster` and `MD1` aliases are not available at the level you and the OP are selecting them.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Didn't observe that select clause. Updated my answer.

Comment: No issues...the OP query is a mess

Answer (score 1):

You structured your query in a very strange way.  I don't know if you need *any* subqueries in there.  But I strongly think that you don't need to have a doubly-nested subquery.  In the query below, I tried to clean things up.  The major problem I saw, and what was probably the immediate cause of the error, is that you were selecting things using aliases not available.

The general rule for SQL is that you can select a column by itself belonging to a table at the same level, a column prefaced by a table name at the same level, or column prefaced by an alias to a table at the same level.  You were not doing this, but the query below is.

```
SELECT
    TAB1.MessageId,
    TAB1.MessageType,
    TAB1.MessageDescription,
    MD1.DetailType,
    MD1.DetailValue,
    MD2.DetailType,
    MD2.DetailValue
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM MessageMaster 
    INNER JOIN MessageMasterDetail
        ON MessageMaster.MessageId = MessageMasterDetail.MessageId
) AS TAB1
INNER JOIN MessageDetail AS MD1
    ON TAB1.DetailId = MD1.DetailId
LEFT JOIN MessageDetail AS MD2
    ON TAB1.AssociatedDetailId = MD2.DetailId;
```